# How would I select certain value from this element

Tags: php, arrays, image

I would like to select the Image Url which is ('http://img.site.com//uploaded/articleThumbnails/DA0AE88C-AB01-4919-9D97-5FDE884A8D9E.jpeg') from the array below, but do not know how.

```
Array
(
    [0] => simple_html_dom_node Object
        (
            [nodetype] => 1
            [tag] => meta
            [attr] => Array
                (
                    [itemprop] => image
                    [content] => http://img.site.com//uploaded/articleThumbnails/DA0AE88C-AB01-4919-9D97-5FDE884A8D9E.jpeg
                )

            [children] => Array
                (
                )

            [nodes] => Array
                (
                )

            [parent] => simple_html_dom_node Object
                (
                    [nodetype] => 1
                    [tag] => head
                    [attr] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [children] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => simple_html_dom_node Object
                                (
                                    [nodetype] => 1
                                    [tag] => script
                                    [attr] => Array
                                        (
                                            [type] => text/javascript
                                        )

                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                        )
```

Comment: how do you get this array? please provide some context as to the initial html, how you use the `simple_html_dom` library and what exactly you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

store your entire array to a variable just for eg. call it as $datas

```
foreach($datas as $data)
{
  echo $data->attr['content'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple element then use this

```
 foreach ($yourArray as $val)
{
  foreach ($val->attr as $val2)
  {
    $getyourURL[] = $val2['content'];
  }
}
```

$getyourURL contain your all URLs

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
echo $arr[0][attr][content];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use This

```
 foreach($datas as $data)
 {
    echo $data[attr][content];
 }
```

or if you want only this field without all in loop use this.

```
echo $datas[0][attr][content];
```